# React Native Flatlist image component flickers when data for the flatlist is resorted

Tags: react-native, mobile, frontend, hybrid-mobile-app

I am actually trying to design a chat application, where i rendered all the chats using a flat lists and i have ordered the chats according to their recent message time in descending order, when the order of chat messages changes, the image in chat component gets flickered. Please suggest me a way to prevent this flickering ,in whatsapp and telegram flickering doesn't happen i want to have the smooth ui experience on my chat app also.

I used React Native for the front end.

Here is the Flat list code..

```
 <FlatList
        data={state.connections}
        refreshing={state.loading}
        onRefresh={fetchLatestData}
        ListHeaderComponent={<Searchbar
            key="editor"
            placeholder="Search me..."
            value={state.searchValue}
            style={{ margin: 15, marginTop: 0 }}
            onChangeText={(value) => { fetchConnections(value) }}
        />}
        ListHeaderComponentStyle={{ width: width * 1 }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {

            let doc_id = getDocId(item.uid, state.userData.uid)

            return <ChatCardComponent key={item.uid} data={item} navigation={navigation} userData={state.userData} latestMessageData={state.chattedFriends.get(doc_id)} />
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item, id) => item.uid}

    />
```

ChatCardComponentCode is,

I have used react-native-expo-cached-image for Image component

```js
 const uri = data.photoUrl;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <TouchableOpacity key={data.uid} onPress={() => { props.navigation.navigate('chatWindow', { data: data, userData: userData }) }}>
                <View style={styles.chatContainer}>

                 
                    <CachedImage
                        style={{ width: 80, height: 80, borderRadius: 60 }}
                        source={{ uri: uri }}
                    />
                    </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
```

Please suggest me fix for this issue.

Comment: Please share your code, or a minimal working code so that others can help you with the issue :) and check whether you have given a key for items in flatlist

Comment: This is a common issue when it comes to a flat list, make sure you are caching the image and then reusing it or memoize the entire item component.

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Please find out the code , I have added it now